# Changing the sort order in questions list in tags section

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is there some way to change the order in which the questions are displayed in SO?
For example, I usually like to search for the tag "mongodb" and then go to the unanswered section. I would like to see all the **unanswered** questions **sorted** by date/time posted rather than the default sort by number of votes. If this feature does not exist, would it be a nice feature to add?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you are viewing tagged questions, simply click the "newest" navigation element to sort questions by the time posted. Your choice will persist through future navigation.

[image]

Note that this shows all questions, not just unanswered ones. To get what I think you want, try a custom search with the tag and `answers:0` to specify no answers.

[image]

Comment: But this shows all the questions, but the feature I was looking for was: unanswered questions in order of date/time (display all the newest unanswered questions)m not all the questions. I have edited the question to make it clearer. Thanks.

Comment: @Sai I edited the answer already.

Comment: Oh OK the second suggestion works. Thanks. I missed the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Michael Hamptons second option works nicely, but I'd still like to see this formally implemented through the page as it is elsewhere on "unanswered" lists.

I would up-rate, but I don't quite have the rep yet.